# IIS Express 8 in Visual Studio will not load site when Authentication cookie exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

I have an ASP.NET mvc application in VS 2012 running IIS Express 8 for the debugger (with a custom domain and ssl).  Everything was working great until yesterday.  When I launch the debugger, it loads the home page.  I then login (and it launches the login page with ssl).  Once I login though, the site fails to load any non-ssl pages.  SSL pages still work fine but as soon as I try to load a non-ssl page, nothing happens (the browser just sits at "Waiting for ..." until it finally fails).

No code in the application is launched when I try to browse to a non-ssl page nor are any logs created in IISExpress.  It is as if the binding on IIS Express does not exist.  If I clear the cookies on the browser, then I can browse the site no problem again (even without restarting IISExpress)

I believe the problem started when I opened a different project with the same name - causing some sort of conflict in the configuration of IIS Express or the VS project.  This should have worked fine as IIS Express added a (1) to the site it created in its configuration but the problem seemed to start then.  To try and resolve the problem, I have tried recreating all of the IIS settings (removing everything and re-adding just the one project, regenerating the applicationHost.config file, removing and re-adding the urlacl entries using netsh, verifying the ssl certification using netsh).

If I manually start IIS Express (iisexpress.exe /Site:"[site name]") then everything works fine - it is only a problem when IIS Express is started by the Visual Studio 2012 debugger.

Comment: I just fixed the problem by installing Visual Studio Update 2.  After installing the update everything works again just fine.  Not sure what fix in the update actually fixed the problem (or what the problem was) but its fixed. I'm a newbie so I cannot answer this question myself for a little while.

Comment: So ... I was wrong - the problem is not fixed - just not as bad with update 2.  Now, if I start the debugger, everything works fine provided that I do not already have a persistent authentication cookie saved.  I can log in and browse both ssl and non-ssl pages no problem.  If it make my login persistent though, then the next time a launch the debugger it will cause the same error (i.e. no problem browsing ssl pages but does not even hit IIS Express on non-ssl pages).